# Typing 'git log --oneline' in oh-my-zsh pipes to 'less'

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just switched to [`Oh My Zsh`](http://ohmyz.sh) and I'm using the [Avit](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/avit.zsh-theme) theme.

When I type `git log --oneline` my output seems to be piped to `less`. It does this for whatever theme I use.

When I used `bash` shell, it never cleared the screen to output those lines.

How do I set it up so that it doesn’t clear the screen to output lines but instead just output the lines after I type the command?

Here's a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Please check first the output of `which git` and `echo $GITPAGER`. And second, if `git --no-pager log --oneline` works as expected.

Comment: This lead me in the right direction. I ended up running `git config --global core.pager ''`. If you answer this question, I will checkmark your post. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a pager, which `git` uses by default for its output via

1. the `$GIT_PAGER` or `$PAGER` environment variable
2. the git config entry `core.pager`

The pager can be temporary disabled with the git command line option `--no-pager`. How to make it permanent depends upon the both possibilities above:

1. find, where in your shell's config files the `$GIT_PAGER` or `$PAGER` environment variable gets defined and remove that line.
2. run `git config --global core.pager ''`

Answer (score 44):

`oh-my-zsh` runs `less` command with `-R` (repaint). You can disable this behavior by adding the following line **at the end** of your `~/.zshrc`

```bsh
unset LESS;
```

This is set to `-R` in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49267711/1050554.

Comment: I thought this comment does not work, but it does, I missed the part of adding unset to the END of zshrc

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO... it's not a git thing but oh-my-zshs

Comment: @josemigallas Absolutely. This "feature" of oh my zsh is ridiculous.

Comment: `-R` is nice to keep colors. Based on this and zqb-all's solution, setting `LESS=-RFX` works nice for me

Answer (score 24):

maybe a better solution :

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager "less -F -X"
```

from [How do I prevent git diff from using a pager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183900/how-do-i-prevent-git-diff-from-using-a-pager)

Comment: This is really better. I'll explain why: with "plain" less, when you do, for instance, `git log` – all your history disappears after you quit the pager. With this command, it stays on screen. If the log is really short (fits the screen) — it doesn't use the pager at all. Only if content is long enough, it would be wrapped in pager, and you'll not lose the screen after clicking "q".

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to fix this is to make `git log` not use the pager in the global configuration settings:

`git config --global pager.log false`

Answer (score 2):

Edit file `~/.zshrc` and add

```
PAGER=
```

Then, save the file and execute `source ~/.zshrc`.